# How to increase Response Time Out in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I create one simple scene for Checking requests and response time. I simply Request using like below.
My while loop for handling a Response.

```
        while(true)
            msg = Wait(0, m.port) ' 100 millisecond pause
'            statusCode = msg.GetResponseCode()   ' check status code is working or not
            print "Response wait for 10 Second pls Wait +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"

            if (type(msg) = "roUrlEvent")
                ?"event display here"
                statusCode = msg.GetResponseCode()
                headers = msg.GetResponseHeaders()
'                data = msg.getstring()

                if msg.getresponsecode() = 200 then
                    data = msg.getstring()
                    headers = msg.getresponseheadersarray()
                    print "***************HEADERS******************"
                    for each header in headers
                        print header
                    end for
                    print "***************DATA*********************"
                        print data
                        m.top.GlobleEPGURL = data

                    print "****************************************"
                    ?"statusCode value here : " statusCode
                    exit while
                else
                    readInternet.asynccancel()
                    ?"here not valid username and password"
                end if
            else
                ? "do something useful while we wait for data"         
            end if

        end while
```

It takes around 15sec to 20sec. Anyone knows How To increase the timeout on the Roku site. I read some website not exactly 0 stands For infinite But another set-top box like android and ios It handles the 110-sec response. So Why Roku device handles only 15 sec. I don't know what I'm Doing wrong pls Help.

**EDITED POST :**

my init() code is here and I already mention my while loop in above

```
readdata = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
data = "http://" + m.top.globleurl + "/api/DefaultAPI/?name=" + m.top.globleusername + "&pass=" + m.top.globlepassword
readdata.EnableEncodings(true)
readdata.setUrl(data)
m.port=createobject("roMessagePort")
readdata.setport(m.port)

readdata.gettostring()
readdata.SetRequest("POST") ' Here I check also Get
request = readdata.AsyncPostFromString(data) ' Here I check also AsyncGetFromString
```

and my xml file is Below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<component name="Login" extends="Task">
<interface>
    <field id="GlobleURL" type="string" onChange = "GetAuthData"/>
    <field id="GlobleEPGURL" type="string"/>
    <field id="globleusername" type="string" onChange = "GetAuthData"/>
    <field id="globlepassword" type="string" onChange = "GetAuthData"/>
</interface>
<script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/components/Login.brs" />

</component>
```

Here I create separate File For Request and Response and that File I append with below Code.

```
m.loginscreen = CreateObject("roSGNode", "Login")
m.top.appendChild(m.loginscreen)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not response time issue. Most probably you are blocking the main thread. If main thread will get blocked for more than 15 sec, or if you are requesting in synchronous way, then timeout will be approx 15-20 sec. Moreover it may lead to crashing the application. To overcome this type of issues, try it with ***'Task'*** node and receive the response using asynchronous methods.

Comment: I already used task node for this and receive response using AsyncPostFromString. But here task node navigate into scene onkeyevent is their any issue. My application crash after 12 Sec.

Comment: Hi @NikunjChaklasiya, try with AsyncGetToString. If still you are facing issues, please try to share more inforation.

Comment: Still, I'm Facing the Same issue. Response Time handle only 10-second then the application was crashed.

Comment: I Edit my Post Pls Check

Comment: I think I'm not sure. Here By Default Set TimeOut Property or Event Set is 10-12 Sec. I can change Mannually?. Here the wait response ` msg = Wait(0, m.port)` But I searched But not Found any property or event to increase a TimeOut.

Comment: Check your code properly. Seems you are blocking your main or rendering thread somewhere.

Comment: OK, Thank you. I will check all the code and inform you.

Comment: I debug my code I successfully request to the server and then after `readdata.gettostring()` Gives Error Member function not found in BrightScript Component or interface. I simply send true or false in Response its work perfect.

Comment: Hii Swaran, I used Request-Response using Task Node. and append child task node with the scene. Here, I wrote append child code in onKeyEvent() in ok key. Now ok press to fire the key event and terminate after 10 seconds. Here I use Hide/Show Concept for navigation. this above problem solved using view stack? I mean using ViewStack to solve a problem for "handle render thread"?

Comment: Hide/Show means I write multiple screen codes in a single file and manually view Hide and Show.